# 'Object' has not been declared error

Tags: c++, object, parameters, syntax-error, declaration

I'm new to c++ coming from Java so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here
the following line in `person.h` is giving me the error `Transaction has not been declared`.

```
void pay(Transaction transaction);
```

I have a Transaction object, do I have to declare / include it in the `person.h` file somewhere?

here is my `person.h` source

```
#ifndef PERSON_H_
#define PERSON_H_

#include "Transaction.h"

using std::string;

class Person {
public:

    class Transaction;

    Person();
    virtual ~Person();
    void pay(Transaction* transaction);
};

#endif /* PERSON_H_ */
```

Comment: You need to include the file that declares the `Transaction` object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++, seperating the declarations from the definitions is a big thing.  Declarations tell how to use the code, and are in header (`.h`) files.  Definitions are the code itself, and are in source (`.cpp`) files.

If a file only refers to `Transaction` by pointer or reference (as is common in a header), then you only need to predeclare the transaction class, with `class Transaction;`.  If the file needs an actual Transaction value, then you need to `#include "Transaction.h"`.

If it *still* says `Transaction` is an undefined symbol, that means you have a circular dependency: A series of headers that include each other in a loop.  In that case, you need to alter one of the header files to only use pointers and references, and predeclare the classes in the other headers.

Comment: I've updated my post, have a look :S and I've only got two classes so I don't know what might be wrong :S

Comment: move `class Transaction;` to _outside_ of the class (in the global scope).  Sorry I wasn't specific.

Answer (score 3):

When you declare a class inside another class, you're declaring an internal class.

So

```
class Person {
public:

    class Transaction;
};
```

Declares a class whose fully qualified name is Person::Transaction. Even if there is another class named Transaction at global scope, references to Transaction will be assumed to refer to Person::Transaction. Since you haven't defined that class, you get your error.

What you want is ::Transaction, either from including the header or from forward declaring outside your class declaration. Do either

```
class Transaction;
class Person {
};
```

OR

```
#include "Transaction.h"
class Person
{
};
```

The former only allows passing by reference. Passing by value or calling a function requires the full class definition provided by include.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of (at least) two possible causes for this:

- Are you sure the forward declaration of `Transaction` is supposed to be in `Person`? That would mean `Transaction` is a nested class in `Person`.
- Are the header files including each other, i.e. is there a cyclic dependency?

Answer (score 1):

you have to include the header file where the Transaction is defined (if you would have used a pointer then you could just forward declare the Transaction class in your h file and include the Transaction.h only in the implementation file).

Comment: Well I did `#include "Transaction.h"` and it's still giving me the same error! and how do I use a pointer ?

Comment: A pointer to a Transaction is `Transaction*`.  A reference to a Transaction is `Transaction&`.

Comment: @MooingDuck, did `void pay(Transaction* transaction);` but still giving me the same error :S

Answer (score 0):

`#include "Transaction.h"` at the top of your file should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting more code.  Try this:

1. In the person.h file, at the top put: `class Transaction`
2. In the person.cpp file, at the top put: `#include "Transaction.h"`

Hope this helps